# How to use IBM Application performance manager to monitor the performance of IBM Cloud native application?

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, apm

IBM Provide APM as SaaS service to monitor the application performance end to end with insights to code and transaction. It require its collection agent to be installed in various application component to collect the metrics. I can see one o the application template supported in the IBM Cloud (Bluemix) application. I like to use the same to monitor my IBM Cloud native application. Application being in cloud, I am assuming that all the collection agents are automatically installed or I can configure them somehow. Once that is done, APM should help me connect to these application and start monitoring them. While This is my understanding, I do not see any document/article which can provide me the steps to configure the IBM Cloud application for APM integration and connection. Can anyone has experience in monitoring such a application ? Can anyone share article to steps to achieve the same ?

Thanks
Manoj

Comment: What does "IBM Coud native application" mean in this context? If it's just an application running in Liberty, what's insufficient in the APM manual?

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKFH/com.ibm.apmaas.doc/install/was_config_dc_all.htm

Comment: IMO configuration of an application server is on-topic, but asking for a walkthrough of how to use a commercial monitoring product is not.

Comment: IBM Cloud being a PaaS, I expect that there is a buildpack with data collector configured for me. Having to configure the Liberty server and pushing the server along with the application defeat the purposes of PaaS

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the details of monitoring Liberty-based applications are described pretty well in the APM manual:

> Configuring WebSphere® Applications monitoring involves configuring a
>   data collector for your application servers. The data collector can be
>   either stand-alone or embedded with the WebSphere Applications agent.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKFH/com.ibm.apmaas.doc/install/was_config_dc_all.htm

> Configuring the data collector for WebSphere Applications agent The
>   WebSphere Applications agent does not need any configuration after
>   agent installation, unless you want to change the default port.
>   However, you must configure the data collector, which is a component
>   of the agent, to set up monitoring for your WebSphere environment.
>
> Configuring the Liberty data collector for on-premises applications To
>   monitor the Liberty profile on Linux for System x, you can directly
>   deploy a stand-alone data collector to your local Liberty directory
>   without installing WebSphere Applications agent.
>
> Configuring the Liberty data collector for IBM Cloud applications To
>   monitor a Liberty profile running in the IBM Cloud environment, you
>   must download the data collector package from IBM Marketplace, deploy
>   the data collector to your local application files, and then push the
>   updates to IBM Cloud.

Comment: IBM Cloud being a PaaS, I expect that there is a buildpack with data collector configured for me. Having to configure the Liberty server and pushing the server along with the application defeat the purposes of PaaS

Comment: IBM Cloud is not a PaaS. It contains a Cloud Foundry based PaaS.  "Why doesn't the Liberty Buildpack automatically interop with APM" is not IMO a programming question suitable for stack overflow, even if you had asked it directly.